# Comparing two DE problems and comparing how to solve them

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So let's say use the function $y=Ax+B$ to solve

$y'=sin(y-x)$

This I know how to do, as $A=1$ and $B=\frac{π}{2}$.

But what if the problem was $y'=1.001sin(y-x)$?

I have a feeling that the 1.001 has a significant effect on the problem, but I don't get what I'm supposed to do with the extra number.

Comment: $a/1.001 = \sin(x(a-1)+b)$

Comment: Ok, I got to $\frac{1}{1.001}=sin(B)$, but I feel like I missed something - it feels too similar to the first problem.

Comment: See answer I added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We get:

$$\dfrac{a}{1.001} = \sin(x(a-1)+b)$$

We can do two things:

- Set $a=1 \rightarrow  b = 2 \pi n+\pi-\sin^{-1}(1000/1001),   n \in \mathbb{Z}$
- $a-1 \ne 0,   x = \dfrac{-\sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1000 a}{1001}\right)-b+2 \pi n+\pi}{a-1},   n \in \mathbb{Z}$
- In both cases above, you can leave out the $\pi$ term that is by itself.
- You also have take some care with $a$ for obvious reasons (either divide by zero or for the inverse sine term).

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know simply adding a 1.001 complicated things so much.  Thank you for explaining - I'll go over the problem again myself to try to understand.

Comment: @user91971: You are very welcome. The solution provided is very general, so take your time and make sure you understand it. If you make $n = 0$ and leave out the single $\pi$ term, it may make more sense to you. Regards